# Android TextView drag & drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to implement drag and drop functionality with `SDK >= 8`. I want to drag `TextView` elements and drop it on other views.

In support library there is a new `MotionEvent` class, which I can use to that, but I affraid that I cannot handle it. I saw some of tutorials with canvas, but I do not want to use it.

Can someone in simple code just tell me how I can achieve simple drag and drop with one `TextView` which can be dropped on one `ImageView`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

For SDK>=11, Android provides a framework for drag&drop.

But for a simple drag&drop for older SDKs, check this site http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html